# Rudder nodes losing link to server?

Tags: linux, rudder

Yesterday I've set up my first Rudder server, with two nodes. All was green.
This morning, everything is orange ("unexpected"), and if I run the client manually I see this message:

```
**************************************************************************** *****
* rudder-agent could not get an updated configuration from the policy server.   *
* This can be caused by a network issue, an unavailable server, or if this      *
* node was deleted from the Rudder root server.                                 *
* Any existing configuration policy will continue to be applied without change. *
*********************************************************************************
```

The nodes are still displayed on the server list with a recent timestamp.

What happened?

Thanks

greg

Comment: How do we know what happened? The two machines aren't talking. It's your network and we have no visibility into it.

Comment: The two machines are talking. For some reason the rudder server stopped understanding the data from the client, while still connecting to it: the timestamp is updated.
Furthermore, the client on the server system also shows problems and I'm pretty sure the server can talk to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the answer from the Rudder IRC people: I was using IP address to avoid DNS problems and it turns out that using IPs is a DNS problems in itself... back to explicit names and it was working again.